# Logical AND operations in Swift not working

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift and trying to solve a very basic **Logical AND** problem

```
if (textField == self.cvv && cvv.text.length == 4 && !string.isEmpty)
{
    return false;
}
```

this is my code

According to this
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html

the && does exists however I am getting error

```
Couldn't find an overload for the &&
```

What and how can I use logical operations?

Comment: it seems like something in your if statement doesnt produce a boolean value to do the logical and with, but from the code you pasted everything seems ok so that is strange

Comment: Question title is now misleading, since it is established to be a Logical AND error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is **not** a logical && error: compiler confused by **an earlier** error:

> 'String' does not have a member named 'length'

---

`count(cvv.text)` is not available either:

[image: there is no universally good answer, see the documentation comment for discussion]

See @RMenke's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32448306/218152) for *Swift 2.0* syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this:

```
var textField = UITextField()

var cvv = UITextField()

var string = ""


if (textField == cvv && cvv.text!.characters.count == 4 && string.isEmpty)
{
    return false;
}
```

I couldn't replicate the error, because I have no idea about the types and declarations of all instances involved. However I got an error on the `text.length` might be a Swift 1.2 => swift 2.0 change. I updated it to `text.characters.count`

To more fully answer your question... 
`&&` always worked fine for me, exactly the way you use it. 
conditon1 **operatorA** condition2 **&&** condition3 **operatorB** conditon4 ...

However the "couldn't find an overload" error is often the result of a type mismatch. Checking an `Int` against a `String` for example.